# Imageview animation start on Swipe gesture

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, imageview, swipe

I've looked through other questions here but none seem to be asking the same as me. I want to be able to flip a coin(my image for imageview) by swiping up on the coin. I already have the animation coded to a button, but want to be able to add that same code to a swipe to give a user the option for either. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an OnTouchListener and a GestureDetector

Here is an example:

```
package com.example.androidlayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        final GestureDetector mDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new GestureListener());
        iv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                // Right to left
                return false;
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                // Left to right
                return false;
            }
            if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                // Bottom to top
                //Your code to flip the coin
                Log.println(Log.VERBOSE,"Coin", "Coin flipped");
                return false;
            }  else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                // Top to bottom
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

I've test it on the emulator, and it works just fine.